# What is the distribution of $x^TAx$ when $x$ is gaussian ($A$ may be not symmetric)

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $A \in \Re^{d \times d}$, $x \in \Re^d$ and each component of $x$ is independently sampled from $N(0,1)$. I wonder what is the distribution of $x^TAx$. To be more concrete, how will the resulting distribution relate to $A$. Note that $A$ may be not symmetric, thus this may be a different problem with previous ones. (e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104040/what-is-the-distribution-of-xcx-when-x-is-a-standard-gaussian-vector))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may replace $A$ by the symmetric $(A + A^T)/2$ and then diagonalize, to see that $x^T A x$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^d c_j Z_i^2 $ where $Z_i$ are independent standard normal random variables.  $Z_i^2$ has a Chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom (or a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $1/2$).

Comment: this is a great trick. Can you please explain how can we infer on $x^\top A x$ from the symmetric $(A+A^\top)/2$ ?

Comment: found the explanation in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307381/why-do-we-assume-that-a-matrix-in-quadratic-form-is-symmetric